# mvc 3 view data validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i'm trying to put DropDownList validation to work.

in model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "this field is required")]
public int ObjectTypeID { get; set; }
```

in view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownList("ObjectTypeID", string.Empty)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ObjectTypeID)
</div>
```

if the user leaves the selection empty i expect client side validation to alarm. but this does not happen.
what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of system types is that they must have a value when initalized. An integer has a value of "0". Change your model to accept a nullable int:

```
 public int? ObjectTypeID { get; set; }
```

Comment: i understand. yet in this case i would like to prevent null value and have the validation force the client to select a value. but validation does not work. maybe the problem is with the 'string.Empty' that acts as if it is a value (?)

Comment: An integer will never be empty, it will always have a value, of 0. You could also use a regular expression validator to ensure that its an integer.

Comment: You could also roll your own custom range validator:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic2

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, but why not use DropDownListFor?

For client side validation to work I think you need to turn on ClientValidationEnabled & UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled in the web.config for your project, I believe you also need to reference the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js script on your page?

Answer (score 0):

1) You are not loading your dropdownlist

2) Use DropDownListFor in order to match validation with ddl